# NSXMLParser chokes on ampersand &

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, nsxmlparser

I'm parsing some HTML with NSXMLParser and it hits a parser error anytime it encounters an ampersand. I could filter out ampersands before I parse it, but I'd rather parse everything that's there.

It's giving me error 68, NSXMLParserNAMERequiredError: Name is required.

My best guess is that it's a character set issue. I'm a little fuzzy on the world of character sets, so I'm thinking my ignorance is biting me in the ass.
The source HTML uses charset iso-8859-1, so I'm using this code to initialize the Parser:

```
NSString *dataString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding] autorelease];
NSData *dataEncoded = [[dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES] autorelease];
NSXMLParser *theParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:dataEncoded];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You're parsing HTML with an XML parser? How is that ever going to work? (Unless it's well-formed XHTML and doesn't use the HTML entity set.) Either way, a bare ampersand is invalid in both HTML and XML, so you'd need to seek out a parser for real-world broken-HTML, which is a much, much harder job than XML parsing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To the other posters:  of course the XML is invalid... it's HTML!

You probably shouldn't be trying to use NSXMLParser for HTML, but rather [libxml2](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html)

For a closer look at why, check out [this article](http://vgable.com/blog/2009/05/01/nsxmlparser-and-htmlxhtml/).

Comment: Okay, then. Wrong tool for the job? Thanks for the tip. I may have to do that.

Comment: Great point about the HTML, the NSXMLParser part threw me off.  libxml2 seems like a very reasonable alternative.  See this previous SO article:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405749/parsing-html-on-the-iphone

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you have valid XML?  You are required to have special characters like & escaped, in the raw XML file you should see `&amp;`

Answer (score 0):

Encoding the Data through a `NSString` worked for me, anyway you are autoreleasing an object that was not allocated by yourself (dataUsingEncoding), so it crashes, the solution is :

```
NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                             encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];

NSData *dataEncoded = [dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                     allowLossyConversion:YES];

[dataString release];

NSXMLParser *theParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:dataEncoded];
```

Comment: please edit your answer and format the code (it's unreadable as-is)