# Get and display HTML data from SQLite3 (Iphone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I try to retrieve HTML data from my database and display them in a UITextView, the only problem is that I don't know how to tell him that its HTML code and not only  text, for the moment I have that:

```
NSString *aDescription = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(getFicheStatement , 1)];
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to put any styles into a UITextView. If you want to keep the styles that are in the HTML, the simplest thing to do is to put it into a UIWebView. If you don't want to use a UIWebView, you'll have to parse the HTML yourself, then try to style lots of UILabels and put them together, making sure they align properly. You'll have to deal with flowing the text yourself too.

A UIWebView will save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: Ok I see thank you, that seems complicated. Anyway how do you parse the HTML?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405749/parsing-html-on-the-iphone

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you want to try [`UIWebView`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), instead?

Comment: UIWebView is the only way to display the HTML?
I created  a UIView in Interface Builder, so I display many things n different part like Title, short description...
In the description part I just put some <br> in the text, is it really impossible to display?