# How to parse a HTML file at a URL?

Tags: iphone, html-parsing

I am new to iphone development.I am able to parse a Xml file at a URL and retrieve it contents from a particular nodes.

For Parsing at url

```
 NSString * path = @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    [self parseXMLFileAtURL:path];
```

For retrieving  the data i use NSXMLParser .How can i achieve the same thing if i have HTML file at my URL(Source code of the webpage is HTML).Please help me out.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't parse HTML with NSXMLParser, unless if you want parse it markup by markup.

However it exists some library to do this like the libxml2. You can find a mini tuto here: [How to Parse HTML](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/02/24/parsing-html-iphone-development/)

You can also find more information about it at another topic: [parsing HTML on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405749/parsing-html-on-the-iphone)

Comment: The tutorial you gave me a proper idea of approaching my task.I am not able to understand the logic behind the search of h3 tag which has // too