# Extract image URL from HTML text

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In Objective-C what is the best method to extract an image url from HTML text?

I've got a chunk of HTML text which may contain one or more images. I want to be able to get the src URL of each image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind limiting yourself to iOS 4, you can use the new text checking APIs. The one you want is `NSTextCheckingTypeLink` and the `NSRegularExpression` class.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be answered over here: [parsing HTML on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405749/parsing-html-on-the-iphone)

The second answer down has a detailed explanation, however you will just have to change the xpath expression to match your image tags.