# How can I parse 'document.getElementById' values in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I'm having a hard time to figure out how to get the value from the below code.

```
document.getElementById('today-details-1').value = '41';
document.getElementById('today-details-2').value = '30';
```

I'm having my application making a NSURLConnection and it is receiving the contents of the page which are basically 5 more lines like the ones above.

I want to be able to get the value for each of the elements. How would I accomplish this?

I tried nodesForXPath but can't get that to work as this is not really a xml page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
NSString *oneString = [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('today-details-1').value"];
```

Comment: Oh so i have to use a webview? right now i am using NSXMLNode.

Answer (score 0):

For parsing HTML look at this previously asked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405749/parsing-html-on-the-iphone) which has a number of good solutions.

I used [hpple](http://github.com/topfunky/hpple) which is suggested in an answer