# Html file parsing in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

How can I parse an HTML file under iOS? Any tutorials or sample code available?

Comment: You need to parse it to manage the data contained in the html page or you just need to display the html page?

Comment: @lomanf I need to parse data from that html file  and display it in my own view like table view.

Comment: Please go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405749/parsing-html-on-the-iphone

Comment: OK then try to have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405749/parsing-html-on-the-iphone there's a nice example using the "hpple" library

Answer (score 2):

Check out [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It's Apple's class for parsing XML documents. Should be a good start, if you know something about the format of the document in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use XPathQuery to parse HTML or XML conveniently

1. Google XPathQuery for iphone
2. download XPathQuery.h and XPathQuery.m
3. include both files in the project.
4. Use the following method to parse HTML.

```
NSArray *PerformHTMLXPathQuery(NSData *document, NSString *query);
```