# How to read fully RSS content from the link in iOS?

Tags: ios, rss

I want do code a RSS app for the iPad, so I started to read about the xml parser in ios.
Now i can read all the tags like title, link, date and so on but i want to read also the hole text from the link.
How can i do it like the reader in safari?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the RSS feed. Not all RSS feeds contain the entire article. If the RSS feed you are parsing does not contain the entire article, you'll have to parse the page of the link and get the article from there. Or you can do what most (all?) RSS readers do, just have a button to view the link in a `UIWebView`.

Comment: the button with the link i have, but how can i get the website from the link (witch object, also xml parser?)

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405749/parsing-html-on-the-iphone