# Regular expression to match all tags in HTML document in iPhone

Tags: iphone, regex, nsregularexpression

I am developing an application in which I am using HTML documents.Now I want the user to be able to search for a word or phrase through all the documents so i planned to take all the text escaping tags in a string and search for the given word in the string.For that I want a regular expression to identify tags.Currently I am using following regular expression to identify tags:

```
   NSString *regEx=@"<.*>";
```

I know its not a perfect choice.I want suggestions on what expression should I use so that I could identify tags in HTML.I am little confused about how to use escape sequence in the same.Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Relevant.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @Justin:Thanks.I don't have XHTML.Its simple HTML.Can we do it then?

Comment: @Justin is correct, regex cannot be used to parse HTML reliably. You are better off looking for an [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405749/parsing-html-on-the-iphone).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Justin is correct.
I didn't find any such regular expression.