# NSXMLParser cannot handle some HTML entities like &Atilde;

Tags: html, ios4, nsxmlparser

Has anyone run into the XML parser just ending when it encounters HTML entities like Ã?

Thanks
Deshawn

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this problem is because the the XMLParser is using element validation, which will break if it sees an html element like the one you described. If you want to parse HTML you will want to use Hpple.

Check out this post for more information.
[parsing HTML on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405749/parsing-html-on-the-iphone)