# Why is my iOS Regular Expression not working?

Tags: ios, xml, regex, nsregularexpression

I'm trying to get all the XML out of certain tags (not just values but everything including more XML between two open and close tags) and I figured I'd use a regular expression.

My code looks like this

```
NSError *error2 = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<PayloadPost>(.*)</PayloadPost>"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error2];
if (error2)
{
    NSLog(@"Error %@", [error2 description]);
}

NSArray *payloadRanges=[regex matchesInString:theXMLString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [theXMLString length])];
int size=[payloadRanges count];
printf("Size %d",size);
```

Basically I need everything in the "PayloadPost"s and yet it keeps giving me nothing. I keep getting 0 for size and I know the XML has 3 instances in it.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you set the multiline flag, https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators

otherwise the '.' character will not match the line break and your regex will match

```
<PayloadPost>something</PayloadPost>
```

but not

```
<PayloadPost>
something
</PayloadPost>
```

Comment: Well that worked, after I added in a question mark after the asterisk so it would be non-greedy. Now all I need to do is figure out how to make the strings not include "<PayloadPost>" and "</PayloadPost". That and include multiple options but mainly get rid of payloadposts. Thanks for your help.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822356/capture-groups-not-working-in-nsregularexpression?rq=1

Comment: "more than one" option?.. what do you mean, exactly?

Comment: having say both the dotmatcheslineseparators and the caseinsensitive options for the same NSRegularExpression.

Comment: I assume they should be combined using the bitwise OR operator, as in `NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive | NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators`