# parse a string using NSRegularExpression

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I am trying to parse a string using NSRegularExpression so that I can extract several strings in between predefined phrases:

```
NSString* theString = @"the date is February 1st 2000 the place is Los Angeles California the people are Peter Smith and Jon Muir";
NSString *pattern = @"(?:the date is )(.*?)(?: the place is )(.*?)(?: the people are )(.*?)";

NSError *error = nil;

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];


NSArray* matches = [regex matchesInString:theString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, theString.length)];
```

I am expecting to get 3 matches:

February 1st 2000
Los Angeles California
Peter Smith and Jon Muir

However it looks like I am not putting the regex groups properly. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1: With Group Matches**

```
the date is\s*(.*?)\s*the place is\s*(.*?)\s*the people are (.*)
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/rQ5fX9) (make sure to **look at the Groups** in the lower right pane)

It can be tweaked further of course. :)

The idea is that the parentheses capture the text you want into Group 1, Group 2 and Group 3.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6822915/1078583) gives an idea of the syntax to retrieve Group matches in Objective C.

**Option 2: Straight Matches, using lookarounds**

A bit more unwieldy:

```
(?<=the date is ).*?(?=\s*the place is)|(?<=the place is ).*?(?=\s*the people are)|(?<=the people are ).*
```

See the [demo](http://regex101.com/r/zJ6bD1)

Comment: This is great, thank you. I like the site especially.