# regular expression for a serial number

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

I have this long payload and I need to return a serial number from it but it has many serial numbers and I only want to return the serial number after a certain tag. Here is the payload:

```
USB:

USB 2.0 SuperSpeed Bus:

  Host Controller Location: Building

    Internal Card Reader:

      Product ID: 0x8406
      Serial Number: 000000000820 //i dont want this
      Building: Yes

USB 2.0 Bus:

  PCI ID: 0x8c31 


    iPhone:

      Vendor ID: 0x05ac  (skyway Inc.)
      Version: 7.02
      Serial Number: wea0aa752ada7722ac92575e98z2e89c691f4282 //i want this
      Speed: Up to 492 Mb/sec
      REC ID: 0x11100000 / 1

    skyway Internal Keyboard / Trackpad:

      Product ID: 0x0162
      Recog ID: 0x05ac  (skyway Inc.)
      Location ID: 0x14c00000 / 3
      Current Available (mA): 500
      Built-In: Yes
```

How can I build a regular expression that will return to me only the following:

```
wea0aa752ada7722ac92575e98z2e89c691f4282
```

I tried doing the following but that will return all expressions that start with serial number:

```
Serial Number: [0-9]
```

I just want the serial number that shows up after the iPhone title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\\biPhone:[\\s\\S]*?\\bSerial Number: (\\w+)
```

Try this and grab the group 1.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hF7zZ1/5

[For Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822356/capture-groups-not-working-in-nsregularexpression)

```
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
//NSRange matchRange = [match range];
NSRange matchRange = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
NSString *matchString = [htmlString substringWithRange:matchRange];
NSLog(@"%@", matchString);
}
```

Comment: awesome but is there anyway to grab the first group from the regular expression itself.

Comment: @j2emanue there is only one group present.. dont know much about this language :(

Comment: @vks not needed why? `(?:(?!\\n\\n).)+` asserts that there isn't any empty line present inbetween. But's you'rs fails in that case. So this would match the string `Serial NUmber` from the paragraph which exists next to the iphone.

Comment: @AvinashRaj its simply not required....OP just wants serial number after iphone..... dats it...you are making it overcomplicated!!!!!!The format seems pretty fixed to me

Answer (score 1):

Use Capturing group.

```
"(?s)\\biPhone:\\n\\n+(?:(?!\\n\\n).)+\\bSerial Number: (\\w+)"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qP8jO8/1)

Comment: Note that he wants the Serial Number *after* "iPhone"

Comment: im trying this but its not working ..does it work for you if you go to http://rubular.com/

Comment: i get this error in rubular.com    Undefined group option.

Comment: rubular is speciall created for ruby, which won't support s modifier. In that case, you may use `\biPhone:\n\n+(?:(?!\n\n)[\s\S])+?\bSerial Number: (\w+)`