# Iphone-TFHpple- having trouble with Xpath for HTML

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xpath, xcode4

I'm new to objective c and trying to parse HTML with TFHpple, and having trouble with Xpath.

Currently I'm  trying to get news topic from main page of Yahoo Japan. but it return nil.

```
NSStringEncoding UTF = 4;
NSString *htmlWillInsert = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yahoo.co.jp/"] encoding:UTF error:nil];
NSData *htmlData = [htmlWillInsert dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
TFHpple *xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:htmlData];
NSArray *elements = [xpathParser searchWithXPathQuery:@"/html/body/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li/a"];   

NSLog(@"%@", elements);
for (TFHppleElement *element in elements)
{  
    NSLog(@"%@", [element content]);
}
[xpathParser release];
```

i could get html from yahoo.com . but can't get anything from yahoo JP.

dose any1 know the solution?

Comment: Add a log of the raw response. Maybe yahoo.jp is in html (in opposition to xhtml) so you can't parse it as xml!

Comment: thanks for a comment Geoffroy.My debug log says...2011-10-12 19:31:13.481 TFHpple _Test[20685:b303] Nodes was nil.
2011-10-12 19:31:13.483 TFHpple _Test[20685:b303] (
)     and i think yahoo Jp is xhtml.dosent make sense why it doesn't

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
-> Yahoo.jp, so it's not xhtml.

Comment: oops..sry about it Geoffroy.so...do you know any other way to parse html?or other component likes TFHpple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As yahoo.jp is in html and not xml, you can't parse it as such.

To parse HTML, you can see the examples given in this post : [parsing HTML on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405749/parsing-html-on-the-iphone)

Comment: You're welcome. Did this answer your question or do you have something more? if not, accept the answer

Comment: Yes it dose.And i accepted. Sry I'm new to here and thanks anyways =D