# Best way to parse parts of HTML in Cocoa

Tags: html, cocoa

I downloaded a webpage into a NSString but am only interested in certain pieces of the webpage.  I used "componentsSeparatedByString" to get to one of the 8 parts of the page, but it seems very inefficient to keep repeating this for each piece, as well as each sub piece that gets processed after getting the result of that function.  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: See parsing HTML on the iPhone [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405749/parsing-html-on-the-iphone][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405749/parsing-html-on-the-iphone

Answer (score 0):

**Module [HTMLparser](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-HTMLparser.html) from libxml2**
this module implements an HTML 4.0 non-verifying parser with API compatible with the XML parser ones. It should be able to parse "real world" HTML, even if severely broken from a specification point of view.