# IOS and XML parser (reading file )

Tags: iphone, ios, xml

I am new in IOS. and i was looking for a tuto or small example in how to read from a local xml file in my ressources but i found nothing....any one with a good tuto or have worked with xml before i really need your help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323326/xml-parsing-in-ios-tutorial

Comment: a very simple example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109032/how-to-read-html-as-xml-in-iphone/9109924#9109924

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best XML parser for Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) you have the `NSXMLParserDelegate` doc with examples

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for reading the xml file:

```
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myLocalXML" ofType:@"xml"];  
    if (filePath)
    {  
        NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath];  
        if (myText)
       {  
            NSLog(@"XML : %@",myText);
            NSData *xmlData = [myText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData];
            parser.delegate = self;
            [parser parse];
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the following link will help you adding parser provided by apple

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/parsing-an-xml-file/

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Name of your xml here...." ofType:@"xml"];
```

use the e above code to access file from your project and provide it to above parser for parsing

Answer (score 0):

[**TBXML**](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html) is my favorite. You can download project from [**git hub**](https://github.com/71squared/TBXML).
And why is this my favorite is because it's easy to understand and also it's performance is high.
Read this blog for more
[**How To Choose The Best XML Parser for Your iPhone Project**](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project)