# REGEX to Parse Text From Webpage in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, regex, parsing

I am working on updating some of my iOS blog apps to get beyond using UIWebViews that load the article URL.  I would like to do something more along the lines of Engadget or TUAW where the text from the article and the main picture is all that is loaded when you click on an article from the tableview, but I am having issues getting only the text of the article.

I tried using some DOM Property codes to get the innerBodyText of the HTML, but no matter what DOM property I try, I end up getting header/footer info, advertisements, and more thrown in with the article.

Is there a simple way in iOS using REGEX or something else to get just the text of the article?

Comment: you will need to find the exact dom element nothing less nothing more, for example try this inside this page $(".postcell")[0].innerText

Comment: I am writing this for an iOS app, so some actual iPhone code would be useful.

The HTML code used on the blogs in question is:

<h1 class="entry-title">TITLE</h1>

<div class="entry-content">

Comment: what is the blog you are using?

Comment: I'll be using a few different ones eventually, most are created with wordpress.org though.  Here is the current one working on:

http://316apps.com/ipreachersblog/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend looking into [Hpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple)

[see this thread for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405749/parsing-html-on-the-iphone)