# HTML Parsing Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, html-parsing

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>this value i want to grab</title>
  </head>
  <body> </body>
</html>
```

I have this NSString html, and I want to grab value in tag title?
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405749/parsing-html-on-the-iphone

Comment: You can use Objective-C-HTML-Parser. Check [here](https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser) for more detail.

Answer (score 4):

Use `NSXMLParser`, together with `NSXMLParserDelegate`.

In your case it is really simple. You just watch for `@"title"` in `parser:didStartElement` and in `parser:foundCharacters:` add the content to your own string variable, finalizing it on `parser:didEndElement:`.

Comment: XHTML is becoming the standard (HTML in proper XML syntax), but even normal html can usually be parsed as XML. No reason to downvote this answer.

Comment: This will work very well. The structure of XML and HTML is similar. I have used this in the past successfully. Don't understand the down-vote. :-(

Comment: No reason to downvote. It's yet better/more elegant than running some messy JavaScript in a web view. Wasting his shot. +1.

Comment: XML and HTML may look similar, but HTML parsers operate under [significantly different rules than XML parsers](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/HTML_vs._XHTML).

Comment: @一二三 In the very document you reference it is stated that modern HTML (HTML5) is indeed XML. I do not see how the differences mentioned in the document would lead to errors with `NSXMLParser`. Software is about solving practical problems, not conceptual fundamentalism.

Comment: The document is somewhat outdated in that respect: HTML5 comes in [two syntax flavours](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/introduction.html#html-vs-xhtml), only one of which is a type of XML. Things `NSXMLParser` will not handle include [void elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-elements) (`<br>`, `<img>`, etc.) and other tag omission rules (like those on [`<p>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html#p-tags)). Use of these features exists, is recommended by the W3C, and is not "conceptual fundamentalism".