# Adding HTMLParser library Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser) to add a library for HTMLParser.

However, I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_HTMLParser", referenced from:
```

I read many answers in stackoverflow but couldn't find a solution.

I develop for iphone and ipad and using xcode 4.5

Comment: are you sure you added the HTMLParser.m to your target? . the error tells you that it has not been compiled

Comment: I created a new group called HTMLParser and added all 4 files there.

Comment: also, if I import #import "HTMLParser.h"
#import "HTMLNode.h" it doesnt show compilation errors

Comment: are there any other errors or warnings for the HTMLParser.m / HTMLNode.m?

Comment: nope. Only Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_HTMLParser", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ChooseTemplateViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: well, if you're sure it is in the target im stumped (hint: double check if there is a checkmark)

Comment: where would the checkmark be? it looks like any other class in xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use ARC you say but HTMLParser does not, so if you're not getting errors tring to compile it, it is not included & compiled & therefore missing at link time.

see: [How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)

Comment: yes there are according to the picture

Comment: damn ^^ NOW im stumped.. are you using arc?

Comment: yes.(I know cuz I get compilation errors if I try to release objects)

Comment: added a link to a related solution

Comment: Thanks. I had 2 problems:1. the class wasn't in build phases 2. The arc issue. Can you please vote up my question? I think that it was fair..

Comment: yip did it, _I_ didnt vote it down though ;)

Comment: Compiling with or without ARC throws the same error. Not an answer? At least not anymore. Try with latest source