# jsoup like library for iOS

Tags: ios, jsoup

I've used jsoup for an Android project but I haven't been able to find a port to iOS of this same library. Is there something similar available for iOS?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405749/parsing-html-on-the-iphone).

Comment: Can you add and remove elements using Hpple or is it read-only?

Comment: I  have the same problem. Did you get the solution for this ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I had to cook up a custom solution.