# How to make search query on certain web site and display it as native app

Tags: ios, web-applications, web

I have a task to implement but after some thought I don't really know from where to begin.
What I need to achieve:
Lets take as example BestBay web site. From my app I would like to create a certain query which will go/use to BestBay search type what  I need and bring me the result. On my device I would like to show it as 10 views of the first items the website returned. For instance if I type "tvs" I will get a list of tvs so I would like to show this list on my device with the price and the link to the item (at least for the 10 first items).
I have experience with native apps(i didn't worked with web apps).
I **can't** use Best buy api.

I am not sure from where to begin.
I read about [YQL](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-tutorials.html).
I thought maybe to use the web page with the results as html and parse it to the objects I need.
Did anyone do something similar and can give me some starting point.
How to approach this kind of problem.
(tutorials/documentations/sample code something that can help me to start).
Tnx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided to do it by HTML parsing:

[parsing HTML on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405749/parsing-html-on-the-iphone?lq=1)

[How to Parse HTML on iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios)